# Using application.inputbox that returns range in a variant variable

Tags: excel, vba, range, inputbox

B is a variant. how can it hold range? This code does not work for me at least.

How did you set b=a?.

```
sub test()
  Dim MyRange As Range

  testSub Application.InputBox("dada", , , , , , , 8), MyRange 'doing via Sub
  Set MyRange = testFunc(Application.InputBox("dada", , , , , , , 8))

  If MyRange Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "The InputBox has been canceled."
  Else
    Debug.Print "The range " & MyRange.Address & " was selected."
  End If
End Sub

'The sub method:


Sub testSub(ByVal a As Variant, ByRef b As Range)
  If TypeOf a Is Range Then Set b = a
End Sub


Function testFunc(ByVal a As Variant) As Range
  If TypeOf a Is Range Then Set testFunc = a
End Function
```

Comment: I just want to solve this code which I got in stackoverflow by user Dirk Reichel. But I can't. Any help is appreciated

Comment: It works for me (a `Variant` can hold anything). What **exactly** is your problem with it?

Comment: In locals window a appears as "empty". Can't set b = a

Comment: Did you check the `Debug.print` output? As soon as you step into the function code itself, you will see that a is treated as a range object.

Comment: Yes it returns "empty" as typename

Comment: There is no `TypeName` in the `debug.print` lines. Note also the edit to my previous comment.

Comment: Please wait I'm checking

Comment: I found a solution. The problem was I did not create seperate subroutine or function and did not pass value to "a" by Val and value to "b" byref instead I put that code directly in main subroutine. But what happens here?. Any info is appreciated.